# Bokeh - create custom hovertool for a single glyph on patches figure

Tags: python, hover, bokeh, renderer

I created a map roughly following [the texas.py example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html) from Bokeh's documentation. I am trying to add a point on the map that has its own mouseover behavior. I've added the glyph with the following:

```
bc_glyph = Circle(x=barclays_x, y=barclays_y, size=10, line_color="black", fill_color="silver", line_width=1)
```

I attempted to create custom HoverTool behavior with this:

```
bc_ht = HoverTool(renderers=['bc_glyph'], tooltips=['Barclays Stadium'])
```

Then I called `plot.add_glyph(bc_glyph)`. When running my script, I get the following output:

```
ValueError: expected an element of either Auto or List(Instance(Renderer)), got ['bc_glyph']
```

A quick google of the error message leads to [Bryan helping another user with a similar issue,](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/ll_C88vi2OM) so I rewrite as follows:

```
plot_add = plot.add_glyph(bc_glyph)
bc_ht = HoverTool(renderers=['plot_add'], tooltips=['Barclays Stadium'])
```

However, that returns the same error:

```
ValueError: expected an element of either Auto or List(Instance(Renderer)), got ['plot_add']
```

I understand I have fed the wrong input to `renderers`, but I'm not sure how to correct this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still passing a string, `'plot_add'`, as the value. You need to pass the actual variable:

```
bc_ht = HoverTool(renderers=[plot_add],           # no quote around plot_add
                  tooltips=['Barclays Stadium'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow, such a silly mistake. Much appreciated. I also had to remove the [] brackets in tooltips. With those changes,the code no longer returns an error, but it also doesn't display the desired tooltip. It still shows the HoverTool parameters for my plot. The updated code is as follows:
`bc_glyph = Circle(x=barclays_x, y=barclays_y, size=10, line_color="black", fill_color="silver", line_width=1)`

`plot_add = plot.add_glyph(bc_glyph)`

`bc_ht = HoverTool(renderers=[plot_add], tooltips='Barclays Stadium')`

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you can mark the answer correct it will help other users.

Comment: Would you suggest I make a new post to further the discussion? The error is resolved, but the functionality is still not as desired.

Comment: Your `tooltips` value s just a static const string, it does not have any `@` values that reference the columns of the data source. I'd suggest looking over https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool first and then making separate question if necessary.